# v-calendar datepicker date range event after first date is picked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way of triggering an event for the [date range picker of v-calendar](https://vcalendar.io/api/v2.0/datepicker.html) after the first date is picked or stopping the inputs from adding the dates until both dates have been selected?

I have the following vue component:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      range: {
        start: null,
        end: null
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleBlur(event) {
      if (event.currentTarget.value === '') {
        event.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.remove("entered");
      }
    },
    handleFocus(event) {
      event.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.add("entered");
    },
    moveLabels() {
      changeClass(this.$refs.filterDateForm);
      changeClass(this.$refs.filterDateTo);
    }
  }
});


function changeClass(input) {
  if (input.value === '') {
    input.parentNode.classList.remove("entered");
  } else {
    input.parentNode.classList.add("entered");
  }
}
```

```css
@import url 'https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.4/lib/v-calendar.min.css';
.filter__date-range-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 95%;
}

.filter__date-range-column {
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
}

.form__row {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  background: white;
}

.form__control {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.75em;
  background: transparent;
}

.invalid .form__control {
  border-color: red;
  outline-color: red;
}

.form__control:focus {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form__label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(0.75em + 1px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.entered .form__label {
  top: 0;
  left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.6875rem;
  line-height: 0.6875rem;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.invalid .form__label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.4/lib/v-calendar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <v-date-picker v-model="range" :popover="{ visibility: 'focus' }" is-range @input="moveLabels">
    <template #default="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
          <div class="filter__date-range-holder">
            <div class="filter__date-range-column">
              <div class="form__row filter__date-range-row">
                <label class="form__label filter__date-range-label" for="filter-date-from">From</label>
                <input id="filter-date-from" ref="filterDateForm" type="text" name="from" class="form__control form__control--textbox" :value="inputValue.start" v-on="inputEvents.start" @focus="handleFocus" @blur="handleBlur">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="filter__date-range-column">
              <div class="form__row filter__date-range-row">
                <label class="form__label filter__date-range-label" for="filter-date-to">To</label>
                <input id="filter-date-to" ref="filterDateTo" type="text" name="to" class="form__control form__control--textbox" :value="inputValue.end" v-on="inputEvents.start" @focus="handleFocus" @blur="handleBlur">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
  </v-date-picker>
</div>
```

As you can see, the label starts off inside the textbox and animates to the top on focus or if there is a value in the input.  However, with the date range picker, as soon as you select the first date, it updates both inputs with the selected date and so my label is over the value.

I have tried setting the `@input` event of the date picker and putting a watch on the `range` variable, but both only fire once both dates have been selected so I can only move my labels after the second date is selected.

I have also tried adding an `@change` event to the inputs, but as the value is only change via js, the change event is not picked up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by doing the following:

1. Add an `@input` event to handle when date range is selected properly
2. Add a `@dayclick` event to add the entered class when a day is selected
3. Add a timeout to the `handleBlur` method (the `@dayClick` event seemed to take a bit of time to fire so the blur animation started before it kicked in)
4. Add a mutation observer to see if the calendar closes - as the calendar doesn't have a close event, I needed to see if the calendar was closed without valid date range selected - if this happened and the inputs were emptied, this observer removed the entered class

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      range: {
        start: null,
        end: null
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const overlay = document.querySelector('.filter__overlay');

    const config = {
      attributes: false,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };

    // watch to see if calendar is closed
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationsList => {
      mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList' &&
          mutation.removedNodes.length > 0 &&
          mutation.removedNodes[0].classList &&
          mutation.removedNodes[0].classList.contains('vc-popover-content')) {
          removeClass(this.$refs.filterDateForm);
          removeClass(this.$refs.filterDateTo);
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(overlay, config);
  },
  methods: {
    handleBlur(event) {
      const input = event.currentTarget;
      setTimeout(() => {
        removeClass(input);
      }, 150);

    },
    handleFocus(event) {
      event.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.add("entered");
    },
    handleCalendarBlur() {
      changeClass(this.$refs.filterDateForm);
      changeClass(this.$refs.filterDateTo);
    },
    handleCalendarClick() {
      this.$refs.filterDateForm.parentNode.classList.add("entered");
      this.$refs.filterDateTo.parentNode.classList.add("entered");
    },
  }
});

function removeClass(input) {
  if (input.value === '') {
    input.parentNode.classList.remove("entered");
  }
}

function changeClass(input) {
  if (input.value === '') {
    input.parentNode.classList.remove("entered");
  } else {
    input.parentNode.classList.add("entered");
  }
}
```

```css
@import url 'https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.4/lib/v-calendar.min.css';
.filter__date-range-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 95%;
}

.filter__date-range-column {
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
}

.form__row {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  background: white;
}

.form__control {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.75em;
  background: transparent;
}

.invalid .form__control {
  border-color: red;
  outline-color: red;
}

.form__control:focus {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form__label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(0.75em + 1px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.entered .form__label {
  top: 0;
  left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.6875rem;
  line-height: 0.6875rem;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.invalid .form__label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.4/lib/v-calendar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div class="filter__overlay">
    <v-date-picker v-model="range" :popover="{ visibility: 'focus' }" is-range @input="handleCalendarBlur" @dayclick="handleCalendarClick">
      <template #default="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
          <div class="filter__date-range-holder">
            <div class="filter__date-range-column">
              <div class="form__row filter__date-range-row">
                <label class="form__label filter__date-range-label" for="filter-date-from">From</label>
                <input id="filter-date-from" ref="filterDateForm" type="text" name="from" class="form__control form__control--textbox" :value="inputValue.start" v-on="inputEvents.start" @focus="handleFocus" @blur="handleBlur">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="filter__date-range-column">
              <div class="form__row filter__date-range-row">
                <label class="form__label filter__date-range-label" for="filter-date-to">To</label>
                <input id="filter-date-to" ref="filterDateTo" type="text" name="to" class="form__control form__control--textbox" :value="inputValue.end" v-on="inputEvents.start" @focus="handleFocus" @blur="handleBlur">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
    </v-date-picker>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note this example works differently to the one in my site - for some reason the one in my site will remove the dates from the inputs if only one date is selected  - this one seems to keep it